# Sitecore SXA 1.7.1 PageList rendering to appear in 3 column layout

Tags: sxa

I have a list of article items in my content tree #

Article List

- Article 1
- Article 2
- Article 3

My article List page should display a promo(image , title , short description , Article type) of all the articles sorted by publish date

We tried using the  PageList for this functionality and is working as expected

we would want the promo's to be listed as in a 3 column layout instead of rows , how do we achieve this in Sitecore SXA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to style Page List as you want in your theme. You can either style it using Page List CSS class (investigate the HTML and you will see that the Page List is using `page-list` class) or style Rendering Variant which your Page List is using.

You can either assign global variant class:

[image]

Or assign CSS classes to particular Variant items:

[image]

Comment: Please check https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/16630/3035