# How to apply bootstrap classes to "li" items of Pagelist component in Sitecore SXA?

Tags: sxa

I want to show my items in pagelist component horizontally in sets of 3. the default behaviour shows item in vertical list. So in order to show items horizontally, i need to apply bootstrap classes "col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" to "li" items. I tried adding classes through rendering variants and to pagelist component in exeperience editor, the classes are getting added to its parent div.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots where it is shown where you have added classes? I think that you are adding classes to Default or root node in rendering variant not to the correct location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it isn't possible to add those classes via html without cloning the component and modifying the view. However you can achieve the same result using bootstrap mixins and functions in SCSS, with the bootstrap .scss files imported into the theme directory. For example you can add the following to your `theme/scss/variants/search-results` directory:

```
@import "base/bootstrap/_functions";
@import "base/bootstrap/_variables";
@import "base/bootstrap/_mixins";
&.search-result-product {
    ul {
        @include make-row();
    }
    li {
        @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
            @include make-col(12);
        }
        @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
            @include make-col(6);
        }
        @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
            @include make-col(3);
        }
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

Then add a rendering variant to the search results and set a css class of `search-result-product`.

More info about working with SXA themes in Creative Exchange [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/style-sxa-sites-with-sass.html).

Comment: ...thank you for the reply. The first approach you suggested is working !! for the second approach, if i add a new scss file in theme folder, will sitecore compile it automatically ? because i created a new scss files with changes and after using the class name to pagelist component the change is not reflecting

Comment: Hi @Fahmida sorry, some assumed knowledge about SXA Creative Exchange. I've added a link to my answer as to how to change the .scss files.

Comment: You can achieve styling using CSS. After adding the style class in component container and custom rendering variant as per your need. You can achieve desired outcome.